# MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE won't work and there's no constraint into the receiving table

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I'm trying to import some information into a database.
I've checked syntax errors and apparently everything is just fine, but it keeps importing just the first row.

This is how do I import:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'importar1.csv' INTO TABLE usuarios FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(deprecated_userNode, userApellido, userDomicilioCalleyNumero, userDomicilioLocalidad, userTelefono, 
deprecated_userID, deprecated_userName, userEmail, userFechaGeneracion, userLastLogin, deprecated_userStatus, deprecated_userRoles)
```

This is how the table that's going to receive the information is set:

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios(
    userID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    userEmail char(50) null,
    userApellido char(50) null,
    userNombres char(20) null,
    userDNI char(15) null,
    userPass char(65) null,
    userFechaGeneracion char(25) null COMMENT 'en formato timestamp',
    userLastLogin char(25) NULL,
    userTelefono char(200) null,
    userCelular char(200) null,
    userDomicilioCalleyNumero char(100) null,
    userDomicilioLocalidad char(80) null,
    userDomicilioProvincia char(80) null,
    userProfesion char(180) null,
    userEstadoCivil char(80) null,
    userEstudios char(80) null,
    nacionalidad char(80) null,
    userAnoticiado char(80) null,
    docFoto char(100) null,
    docDNI char(100) null,
    docCertif char(100) null,
    docVerificada int(1) not null DEFAULT '0',
    comentariosAdmin text null,
    deprecated_userName char(50) null COMMENT 'solamente para cargar los usernames del sist anterior deprecated',
    deprecated_userID int(6) null COMMENT 'userID en Drupal',
    deprecated_userStatus int(6) null COMMENT 'status 0 o 1 en Drupal para los inhabilitados',
    deprecated_userNode int(6) null COMMENT 'Nodo del perfil del usuario en Drupal',
    deprecated_userRoles char(150) null COMMENT 'los roles en drupal',
    userDatosPublicos text null,
    userTelsPublicos varchar(200) null DEFAULT NULL
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And here's some sample information from the csv file:

```
"5383","Webmaster del Sitio",NULL,"0",NULL,"1","webmaster","info@mysite.org","0","1488039755","1","online1,online2,online4,online5,online6,online7,online8,webmaster,online3,online9,autor,suscriptor"
"5384","LOPEZ, Rodolfo",NULL,"Capital Federal -- Villa Crespo","4844-7484 / 15-5558-0556","4","lopez","lopez@fullzero.com.ar","1148746788","1158080258","0","ExAlumno,Directorio"
"5385","Dr. Juan Martinez",NULL,"0",NULL,"8","Dr. Juan M","juanMart@gmail.com","1149090768","1482200545","1","autor"
"5386","Isaac Smith",NULL,"0",NULL,"9","Isaac Smith1","smith@mysite.org","1149100441","0","1",NULL
```

Each item is in one single row.

I've tried:

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r'
LINES TERMINATED BY "\r\n"
LINES TERMINATED BY "\r"
```

What can I do?

Comment: That last column in your sample data leads me to think you might have some data too big for your column type.Also try it with IGNORE 10 LINES.Does it still insert 1 row?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I change the field to VARCHAR(500) and it keeps happening. That field is a list of all user's roles available in the site, it can't get much longer than that first row, as the webmaster of the site has every role .

Comment: I forgot to mention. I try removing rows, and it keeps importing just one line. So maybe there's something wrong with the formatting...?

Comment: Anything changes with `LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"`?

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe that it solved it!! Please post the answer so I can accept it! Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tried all the combinations except one,use the newline

```
LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
```